# How to process annotation and set a default value while creating object

Tags: java, annotations, java-8, java-bytecode-asm, checker-framework

I wanted to write code, which looks like below.

```
MyClass a = new @MyAnnotation MyClass()
```

Assume MyClass method look like below

```
   public class MyClass {

    int a;

    public void setValue(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

}
```

So when some one creats object of MyClass with the annotation, it should set a default value to some x(say 20).

In checker framework, it is allowing us to annotate in the code as below.

```
MyClass a = new @MyAnnotation MyClass()
```

Does any one know how can we get split this into two parts at the time of compiling like below?

```
   MyClass a = new MyClass();
   a.setValue(20);
```

or if we can able to pass defauilt value like below is also fine.

```
MyClass a = new @MyAnnotation(value=20) MyClass()
```

Can this be achieved using annotation processor/ need to use bytecode processor like ASM to get it done?
Updated with more meaningful way.

Comment: why not create a constructor? also your `setValue(a)` returns type of `Test`, but in the body, you returned `this`?

Comment: Changed it to MyClass, it was typo.

Comment: it doesn't make sense, it is an instance method, and return same instance...

Comment: Ignore about the method return. My intention is to set a default value to member when annotation is there at the time of creating object. I tried to run some code by using above syntax but didnt work.

Comment: Please be a bit more elaborate about “but didnt work”. Are you aware that the type annotation feature requires Java 8?

Answer (score 1):

Are you writing a custom type-system via meta-annotations?  That is, are you using the  [SubtypingChecker](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#subtyping-checker) or are have you created your own subtype of BaseTypeChecker?

The short answer is, with meta-annotations you cannot specify this sort of behavior.  The long answer is, if you have a custom checker, then there are a number of ways you can do this.

Keep in mind, however, that writing a custom checker is a fair bit more complicated then using meta-annotations.  But, if you have a custom checker, you can do one of the following:

Option A: Polymorphic Constructors
Steps:

1. Create an @PolyMyAnnotation polymorphic annotation, see [Polymorphic Qualifiers](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#qualifier-polymorphism)
2. Create a PolyMorphic constructor for MyClass, e.g. 
   @PolyMyAnnotation MyClass(@PolyMyAnnotation int a) {}
3. Create a TreeAnnotator that adds @MyAnnotation to the type's of int literals.  See [RegexTreeAnnotator.visitLiteral](https://code.google.com/p/checker-framework/source/browse/checker/src/org/checkerframework/checker/regex/RegexAnnotatedTypeFactory.java#268) for an example.
4. Add your TreeAnnotator to the list of TreeAnnotators used by your AnnotatedTypeFactory.  (See [RegexAnnotatedTypeFactory](https://code.google.com/p/checker-framework/source/browse/checker/src/org/checkerframework/checker/regex/RegexAnnotatedTypeFactory.java#137)

Option B: Use A TreeAnnotator
Steps:

1. Create a class that extends TreeAnnotator
2. Override visitNewClass
3. Identify if the object being constructed is an instance of MyClass (see ElementUtils.getQualifiedClassName and ElementUtils.isObjectType to see how you might do this).
4. If the class being constructed is an instance of MyClass, if so, see if the argument is an Integer literal.
5. If the item is a literal, parse the literal and add it's value to the type being constructed.
   Note, if you would like this to handle non-literals, e.g.
   int a = 20;
   new MyClass(a)

Then you can use the ValueChecker.  IF your type factory extends ValueAnnotatedTypeFactory it will have support for constant propagation.  The data flow API also provides some support for constant propagation.

Option C: Customize dataflow's CFAbstractTransfer Function
However, if you have a custom checker, you can override CFAbstractTransfer.visitMethodInvocation to detect when setValue is called and refine it accordingly.  You can look at [RegexTransfer](https://code.google.com/p/checker-framework/source/browse/checker/src/org/checkerframework/checker/regex/RegexTransfer.java) for an example, or search for methods that extend CFAbstractTransfer or implement TransferFunction.

That said, dataflow is not a substitute for a type-state system (see a discussion of this at [Typestate checkers](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#typestate-checker)).

Comment: I am new to annotations and trying to figure out how can I implement this. I have updated the question with more meaningful way. Can it be done as mentioned by you or need to use ASM?